# How to Troubleshoot Mecab Parser Dysfunction

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, mysqli, mecab

**BACKGROUND**:  I have built a custom search engine that works fine in English, but fails in Japanese, this despite confirmation from my host server that I have performed the installation of the Japanese mecab parser correctly. My own checks reveal the following:

1) **SHOW CREATE TABLE**:

> FULLTEXT KEY `search_newsletter` (`letter_title`, `letter_abstract`, `letter_body`) /*!50100 WITH PARSER `mecab` */
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

2) **SHOW PLUGINS**:

> ngram | ACTIVE | FTPARSER | NULL | GPL |
>     mecab | ACTIVE | FTPARSER | libpluginmecab.so | GPL

**IMPLEMENTATION**

1) **MYSQL Statement**:

> `$sql ="SELECT letter_no, letter_lang, letter_title, letter_abstract, submission_date, revision_date, MATCH (letter_title, letter_abstract, letter_body) AGAINST (? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS letter_score FROM sevengates_letter WHERE MATCH (letter_title, letter_abstract, letter_body) AGAINST (? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) ORDER BY letter_score DESC";`

2) **CUSTOM SEARCH ENGINE**:

See under **Local Search / Newsletters** at https://www.grammarcaptive.com/overview.html

3) **DOCUMENT SEARCHED**:

See under **Regular Updates / Newsletter / Archives / Japanese** at https://www.grammarcaptive.com/overview.html

**COMMENT**:  Neither PHP, nor MySQL complains.  Simply any Japanese word search that needs to be parsed is not returned.  For example, the word 日本語 can be search and found, but does not require any parsing to be retrieved. The search for any other Japanese word in the newsletter fails.

**REQUEST**:  Any troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated.

Roddy

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you can check:

**Does Mecab work on the command line?**

You should be able to do something like this, assuming a linux-like system:

```
echo "日本語ですよ" | mecab
```

Output should be roughly like this (details will probably differ):

```
日本    名詞,固有名詞,地名,国,*,*,ニッポン,日本,日本,ニッポン,日本,ニッポン,固,*,*,*,*
語      名詞,普通名詞,一般,*,*,*,ゴ,語,語,ゴ,語,ゴ,漢,*,*,*,*
です    助動詞,*,*,*,助動詞-デス,終止形-一般,デス,です,です,デス,です,デス,和,*,*,*,*
よ      助詞,終助詞,*,*,*,*,ヨ,よ,よ,ヨ,よ,ヨ,和,*,*,*,*
```

On some platforms mecab is statically linked in MySQL so you don't need a system installation, but [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search-mecab.html) indicate that's not always the case.

**Are your encoding settings correct?**

The default character set of your table is `latin1`, which won't work with Japanese text. I would suggest using utf8, and you'll need to check that your mecab installation supports that.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  Yes, I am able to make it work in command line.  Yes, you are correct about the default setting of the table; it is latin1, but the columns that I have designated for search are all set to utf8.  Does mecab require that the entire table be set to utf8?

Comment: Mecab shouldn't require the whole table to be utf8. Unfortunately I'm not terribly familiar with using mecab in MySQL so if the above doesn't work I'm not sure what to check...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the entire table must be encoded, not just the columns.  Well, at least, this was the one significant difference that I made when I reconstituted the table.

No matter, the parser does not appear in the myPhpAdmin table section where parsers are apparently suppose to appear.  This is, perhaps, due to the way the parser appears in the table's SHOW CREATE statement.  In any case, this is a small shortcoming when compared with the parser's overall functionality.

Roddy